# C if(var & something)

Tags: c, if-statement

Pardon for the silly question but I've been looking at an `fstat()` function demo and one thing keeps bugging me and I can't find an explanation for it, it's this if statement:

`if(variable & something)`, I don't understand what the `&` is suppose to mean in this scenario. I've searched around and couldn't find any useful info, mainly because I don't know what exactly to search. An explanation would be much appreciated, or a redirection to one.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If it's the operator, what about your C book's description is unclear?

Comment: @Spookie Ougi The bitwise AND operator is usually used to check whether a selected flag is set.